# Syntax errors when passing string argument onto function

Tags: c++, syntax-error

Visual Studio (2012/C++) is reporting multiple errors all relaxing to errors in syntax when I cannot see any errors.

I'm calling the function with `Ping(ID);` and ID is a string (Already defined), I've defined the function in the relevant header file as 
`#include <string>
int Ping(string ID);`.

A stripped down version of the function is

```
int Ping(string ID)
{
  // Ping
    cout<<"Pinging\n";
    cout<<ID;
    return (1);
}
```

and the errors in the header file are as follows;

```
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' func.h  3   1
Error   1   error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier   func.h  3   1   
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ID' func.h   3   1
```

I'm really stuck with what I need to do to fix this, so any guidance on how to fix it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not qualify the name with `std::`, as `std::string`.

Comment: Perhaps did not `#include <string>`